# regexp for html p tag with style element

Tags: php, html, regex

Sorry i'm new for regexp, so i need a regexp for this type of tag, exactly for this:

```
<p style="font-family: Georgia;">Text</p>
```

I have a regexp that suits for all p tags, regexp for all p tag is: `<\s*p[^>]*>([^<]*)<\s*\/\s*p\s*>/`
found it on this site. I tried to figure out by myself, i wrote this: `<\s*p[\"\^font\-\family\:\()\Georgia\;\$\"\]*>([^<]*)<\s*\/\s*p\s*>/` but i know it's wrong can anyone help me :) I need regexp exactly for this piece:  `style="font-family: Georgia;"` Thank you.

Comment: Why not use a HTML parser? Writing the regexps yourself may not be the best idea...

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058986/match-all-text-between-two-html-tags-using-regex-php/6059099#6059099) please.

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to match *style="font-family: Georgia;"* use this: `\w+=".+"`

For matching the the entire thing `\s*<p \w+=".+">([^<]*)</p>\s*` can do the trick. This will capture all paragraphs with exactly one attribute with a quoted value.. Not really flexible. If you only want to capture on paragraphs with exactly the font-family georgia style use `\s*<p style="font-family: Georgia;">([^<]*)</p>\s*`

If you find yourself using a lot of regular expressions to "parse" html, a HTML parser might save yourself a lot of trouble. Php's [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class can parse html.

Comment: It don't work for me, i use as you said: 

     if(preg_match_all('\s*<p style="font-family: Georgia;">([^<]*)</p>\s*', $result, $ptag))
        {
            foreach($ptag[0] as $p)
            {
                echo $p."<br />";    
            }
        }

It drops that -> Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: yes you need two include the start/end delimiters of the regex, as such: #\s*<p style="font-family: Georgia;">([^<]*)</p>\s*#